# dataset preprocessing for python AI

Tags: python, pandas, csv, deep-learning, dataset

I am using a keras library to preprocess my data after the initial step of predefining the photos into folder with their classification. I didn't want to manualy do it so I made my own script, but it isn't working, could somebody help debug it? 
It doesn't give a specific error, but it just doesn't finish doing the job and stops at photo `ISIC_0000006`. `wah` is if the photo is classified cancerous, `yay` is if the photo is classified benign cancer. The dataset returns a `1` if it is bad, and `0` if it is okay. I still don't know the problem.
[This](https://challenge.kitware.com/#phase/5840f53ccad3a51cc66c8dab) is the dataset I am using.

By the way, I am only a kid still so please don't expect me to know too much about programming.

**Sample lines from dataset:**

> ISIC_0000000 = 0
>   ISIC_0000001 = 0
>   ISIC_0000002 = 1
>   ISIC_0000003 = 0
>   ISIC_0000004 = 0
>   ISIC_0000005 = 1

**My code:**

```
import pandas as pd
import os
dataset = pd.read_csv('ISIC-2017_Training_Part3_GroundTruth.csv')
dataset = dataset.iloc[:, :-1]
x = 0
xb = 0
xm = 0
prevName = 'ISIC_0000000.jpg'
newName = 'yay/benign1'
while(x <= 1500):
    x = x + 1
    if prevName == dataset.iloc[x-1, 0] + '.jpg':
        if x < 10:
            prevName = 'ISIC_000000' + str(x-1) + '.jpg'
            if prevName == 'ISIC_0000005.jpg': #dataset has random hole so skips over
                x = x + 1
                prevName = 'ISIC_0000006.jpg'
        elif x < 100: 
            prevName = 'ISIC_00000' + str(x-1) + '.jpg'
        elif x < 1000:
            prevName = 'ISIC_0000' + str(x-1) + '.jpg'
        else:
            prevName = 'ISIC_000' + str(x-1) + '.jpg'
        if dataset.iloc[x-1, 1] == 1:
            xm = xm + 1
            newName = 'melanoma' + str(xm)
        else:
            xb = xb + 1
            newName = 'benign' +  str(xb)
        if newName == 'benign' +  str(xb):
            newName = 'yay/' + newName + '.jpg'
            os.rename(prevName, newName)
        else:
            newName = 'wah/' + newName + '.jpg'
            os.rename(prevName, newName)
        prevName = 'ISIC_000000' + str(x+1) + '.jpg'
```

EDIT!!! This is my new code thanks to Abhineet Gupta that is able to go further through the dataset, but oddly stops at photo 34:

```
import pandas as pd
import os
dataset = pd.read_csv('_ISIC-2017_Training_Part3_GroundTruth.csv')
dataset = dataset.iloc[:, :-1]
x = 0
xb = 0
xm = 0
prevName = 'ISIC_0000000.jpg'
newName = 'yay/benign1'
while(x <= 1500):
    x = x + 1
    prevName = 'ISIC_' +  str(x).zfill(7) + '.jpg'
    if prevName == dataset.iloc[x-1, 0] + '.jpg':
        if x == '0000005':
            x = x + 1
            prevName = 'ISIC_000006.jpg'
        if dataset.iloc[x-1, 1] == 1:
            xm = xm + 1
            newName = 'melanoma' + str(xm)
        else:
            xb = xb + 1
            newName = 'benign' +  str(xb)
        if newName == 'benign' +  str(xb):
            newName = 'yay/' + newName + '.jpg'
            os.rename(prevName, newName)
        else:
            newName = 'wah/' + newName + '.jpg'
            os.rename(prevName, newName)
        prevName = 'ISIC_000000' + str(x+1) + '.jpg'
```

Last edit: it turns out it wasn't the codes fault just the .csv file was messed up. Thanks Abhineet Gupta and mrk for the solutions!!!

Comment: could you add a few lines of the csv file, so that it is easier to reproduce your code? Thanks

Comment: I edited the code now! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the above code, the error seems to occur in the following code section -

```
11:     x = x + 1
12:     if prevName == dataset.iloc[x-1, 0] + '.jpg':
13:         if x < 10:
14:             prevName = 'ISIC_000000' + str(x-1) + '.jpg'
15:             if prevName == 'ISIC_0000005.jpg':
16:                 x = x + 1
17:                 prevName = 'ISIC_0000006.jpg'
...
36:         prevName = 'ISIC_000000' + str(x+1) + '.jpg'
```

So, if `x == 5` and `prevName == 'ISIC_0000005.jpg'`,

Line 11 assigns `x -> 6`,

Line 12 and 13 are `true`,

Line 14 assigns `prevName -> 'ISIC_0000005.jpg'`

Line 15 is `true`,

Line 16 and 17 assign `x -> 7` and `prevName -> 'ISIC_0000006.jpg'`

Then, Line 36 (last line) that is outside the `if` statement will assign `prevName -> 'ISIC_0000008.jpg'`

When the loop restarts, Line 11 assigns `x -> 8`,

Line 12 is `false` and program continues until `x > 1500` without entering the `if` block.

To fix the code, I recommend using 
`str(x).zfill(7)` which pads the integer with leading zeros, e.g, for `x = 5` returns `'0000005'` and for `x = 95` returns `'0000095'`. This would eliminate the need for specifying leading zeros based on number of digits in `x`, and simplify your code.

Comment: It let the program advance, but it stopped at 34, any idea why?

Comment: From the code, there does not seem to any reason why it would stop at 34 specifically. In your csv, is there something unexpected happening around the 34th filename?

Answer (score 0):

Since you're reading the `csv` file with `'='` as a delimiter you have to specify that while loading, at least that was the error I experienced when trying to run your code.

**Try changing your line to:**

```
dataset = pd.read_csv('ISIC-2017_Training_Part3_GroundTruth.csv', sep = '=')
```

With this change the code runs for me through the whole csv file you have provided.

***Note:*** A library you should definitely take a look at for image augmentation is to be found [here](https://github.com/mdbloice/Augmentor).

Comment: That wasn't the big problem but it did help! Thanks!